# How I can transmit data from soil moisture sensors 10m away to raspberry pi?

Tags: analog-to-digital, signal

I found this interesting project:
https://hydrosysblog.wordpress.com/hardware/

And I want to apply a soil moisture sensor. But the sensor may be 10m or more (but less than 20m) away from the raspberry pi.

Is there a Way to send Digital To analog signals via ethernet cable or some sort of wireless to the raspberry pi without any software modification?

The sensors that I plan to use is these [ones](https://www.ebay.com/itm/203584699580?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item2f6697fcbc:g:GboAAOSwioVhKfkA&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAABAGh2GzdeFAdAgDjOs2rHB6Aoi8IeyUpGZH9vjS5TRAQesXFZqXsJvJr4ShOpOnUr7X18e6IckGZwhTqKhsA125xBtNa%2FXLS38mLtcHLWuhl2vZlpR6hnYmOvx33xr%2BnhiiXVtak6irCG1Ah0DFWSPSGBNXkQmLeuHmbUy2q6cgNjmVgMvWDVSzeQRWVW1coZZHjmefyeLDtbNCM0T5g05%2BOq1uJsfvPAqj6vl6Bb5dZU3%2BaLOB2zHkIPQPjVnybSZrjqjzrgUBKDsBiCa3qGCJ1KwmAAUOiaPeRqncnS4nS4VGxZ6%2FyVv3q9br0URF9%2BNdox%2FoPWEjMdneSwpVVpdec%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBMkJHZnfpf) (link as reference). I plan to use a total of 4 of them, one for each crop lane.

Comment: Did you read through the [project documentation](https://hydrosysblog.wordpress.com/hardware/)?? What was it you didn't understand?

Comment: what does this mean? ... `without any software modification`

Comment: It appears all of your questions are answered in the documentation, you should probably read it again and take notes. What I did not find is how you are going to power it. It will take a big battery, I am assuming it is in a field not a building.